# Layout - aligning controls to bottom doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following layout

[image]

I want buttons to be at the bottom - all 3 controls should be aligned at the bottom. (Now they're at the top.)
According to documentation (as long as I understand it), gravity or layout_gravity should do the trick but they don't work in this case ?

Following is the code. Please what's the issue ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Show"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text !"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Show"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `android:gravity="bottom"` from parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Paste this

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Show"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text !"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Show"/>
```